# zybooks assignment SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

I am new to coding and taking my first class now. I am also in my first week. In this assignment, I am experiencing this error:

File "main.py", line 15

```
                   ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

There is no line 15

In PyCharm I do not get this error, but in zybooks where the assignment is to be completed, I do. See code below.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
print(user_int)
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
print(user_float)
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
print(user_char)
user_string = input('Enter string:\n')
print(user_string)
# FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space
print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_string)   
# FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse
print(user_string, user_char, user_float, user_int)
# FIXME (3): Convert the integer to a character, and output that character
print(chr(user_int)
```

Comment: `print(chr(user_int)` The last line is missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: When I add them it is the same error.

Comment: There's no way this code would have run on PyCharm with that error.  You must be running different code...

Comment: Copy the contents to a new file and test it to see if you're getting the same error.

Comment: it was a combination of closing parenthesis and whitespace. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I had the closing in pycharm and no space. that is why it worked. in zybooks there was a space between the two closing. ) ) instead of )) which was not easily seen.

Comment: " there was a space between the two closing. ) )" That would not matter. I've never heard of "zybooks", though. You might want to try a dedicated support forum for whatever that is.